# Choosing random strings from an array in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, string, indexoutofboundsexception

Using ten random numbers placed in an array, I want to pick ten random strings from another array, but I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
int[] RandomArray = new int[10]; // this is an array of random numbers between 0 and 21

String[] StringArray = new String[22]; //This array has 22 diffrent sentences and gets them from the string.xml

String[] ResultStringArray = new String[10]; //This array shall have now the 10 randomly picked sentences 

for (int i = 0; i < ResultStringArray.length; i++) {
    ResultStringArray[i] = StringArray[ResultArray[i]];
}
```

What is the problem with the provided code?

Comment: ResultArray has a bigger size than StringArray

Comment: also (more of a convention), your variables should start with lower-case letters. The norm is to use upper case for class names.

Comment: You haven't shown the declaration of `ResultArray`.  You seem to be conflating `ResultArray` with `RandomArray`.

Comment: why don't you just shuffle the array(or better use `ArrayList<String>`instead (it is more flexible then `String[]`) and `Colections.shuffle(...)`) and take first N(10-in your case) elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead:

```
int N=10;
int[] randomArray = new int[N]; // this is an array of random numbers between 0 and 21

String[] stringArray = new String[22]; //This array has 22 diffrent sentences and gets them from the string.xml

String[] resultStringArray = new String[N]; //This array shall have now the 10 randomly picked sentences 

for (int i = 0; i < resultStringArray.length; i++) {
    // Pick the stringArray index from randomArray and not from resultArray
    resultStringArray[i] = stringArray[randomArray[i]];
}
```